# User can unprotect vba protected sheets without providing the password

Tags: vba, excel

I've placed some worksheets protection lines as follows:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

  Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect password, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect AllowFiltering:=True

  Worksheets("Sheet2").Protect password, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
  Worksheets("Sheet2").Protect AllowFiltering:=True

  Worksheets("Sheet3").Protect password, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
  Worksheets("Sheet3").Protect AllowFiltering:=True

  Worksheets("Sheet4").Protect password, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
  Worksheets("Sheet4").Protect AllowFiltering:=True

End Sub
```

However, whenever I click `unprotect worksheet` from the main menu, excel doesn't ask for any password and simply unprotects the sheet. I am doing something wrong here?

Thanks to all!

Comment: Yes - your second protect for each sheet doesn't specify a password, so there isn't one set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect password, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
```

Do that for each line and it should work well, assuming you did put password sting  into the variable `password`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried protecting sheet in just one line and specifying the password string?

Worksheets("Sheet1").protect Password:="YourPassword", UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFiltering:=True